# Suppose $x, y, ε ∈ R$ and $ε > 0$. Prove that if $|x| + |y| < ε$ then $|x − y| < \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis

I think this involves the triangle inequality somehow but I'm stuck on how to use it. I have that $|x-y|\le |x|+|y|\lt \epsilon$ so far, then I'm not really sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost it. Recall that the triangle inequality comes in the shape $$\color{red}{|x-y| \leq |x|+|y|} < \epsilon$$too. To see this from $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$, use $-y$ instead of $y$ there along with $|-y| = |y|$.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know it came like that too, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

The triangle inequality states $$|x+y| \le |x|+|y|$$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now replace $y$ by $-y$. You get

> $$|x-y| \le |x|+|-y| \Rightarrow |x-y| \le |x|+|y|$$